# Is it possible for powershell to download audio file(s) from a local website that doesn't have an ".extension"?

Tags: powershell

so:
I'm currently trying to make PowerShell download an audio file from a local URL link. The problem is however that the URL does not have a .extension at the end of the URL. To elaborate further, this is what the site looks like:

[image]

And I am currently trying to download the file called "4d6a9118-249c-451a-931c-62ee4c07dc07"
Unfortunately, it does not have an extension in the address bar, so whenever I try to do it via PowerShell it doesn't work to download the file. However, if I right-click and press "Save audio as..." it gets saved as a .wma file so that works! I'm just wondering if it's possible to download this file, with no extension, via Powershell?
This is what I've tried so far:

```
$url = "myurl/4d6a9118-249c-451a-931c-62ee4c07dc07"
$filepath = "C:\Users\myname\Desktop\recordings\4d6a9118-249c-451a-931c-62ee4c07dc07.wma"

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -OutFile $filepath
```

This does download the file and saves it, but the content is not included in the file, hence, the audio file is empty! Nothing plays :/

So, my question is, would it be possible to like "force" download this file, even though the address bar does not have a valid extension
(It really doesn't matter if Powershell doesn't save the file as a known extension, I can just convert it myself afterwards, but I'd like the file to be downloaded via Powershell)

---

// Edit

---

I thought so too, but this is all I could find:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
<video controls="" autoplay="" name="media"><source src="theurl/4d6a9118-249c-451a-931c-62ee4c07dc07" type="audio/mpeg">
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure how that will help, as far as I can tell it gives no information of value

Comment: It seems that the WMA file is embedded in the HTML Code. You have to parse the HTML code and find the reference to the WMA file.

Comment: @f6a4 edited :)

Comment: This file seams to me “audio/mpeg” -> mp3

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
$headers = @{
        "Content-Type"="audio/mpeg"
}

Invoke-Webrequest -Uri $requestUri -Headers $headers -OutFile $filepath
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work :/
It still downloads the file, but it contains nothing!
When I right-click and "save as" it is about 25kb big, and when I download it via Powershell it's about 4kb

Comment: I do not think so, seeing as the file is on a localhost URL :/
I could, of course, download it and reupload it somewhere, but then the extension would most definitely be included

Answer (score 1):

It would be the case of first reading the file without the extension of its link, then treating the reference to the audio file, assembling a string for the effective download of the target.

I'm not very familiar with PowerShell, but I can suggest something until some enthusiasts read your question and suggest something better...

```
$Url2Link = "http://string.url/4d6a9118-249c-451a-931c-62ee4c07dc07"
$File2mp3 = $env:tmp+'\'+$Url2Link.split('/')[-1]

$UrlAudio = $((New-Object net.webclient).DownloadString($Url2Link).Split("`r`n") -match 'src='|%{$_.Trim().split('/".*//')[7]})+"/"
$(New-Object net.webclient).DownloadFile($($Url2Link.replace($($Url2Link.split('*/')[-1]),$($UrlAudio+$($Url2Link.split('*/')[-1])))),$File2mp3+'.mp3')
```

This suggests that the string in `source src="`is exactly:

```
...<source src="theurl/ + "String_File_Name_Without_eXtension"
```

---

- For using:

[image]

```
$(New-Object net.webclient).DownloadFile($(gcb),$env:temp+'\'+$((gcb).split('*/')[-1]+'.mp3'))
```

If not the case, please let me know....

Comment: I salute you for trying to solve this, almost two years later, but unfortunately, I am not currently working there any more :/ But thanks regardless for your effort - perhaps someone else on le internet will benefit from it

Comment: I’m see this question only after answer another question that y have..